# Blazor to minimize chat window in .NET using HTML and CSS

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, blazor

I am new to using Blazor and would normally do this in JS but blazor uses C# and I am trying to implement this functionality if possible of using a HTML button to minimize my chat window but I am not sure on how to approach this.

Currently I have my HTML chatbox

```
<div class="chatbox-holder">
        <div class="chatbox">
            <div class="chatbox-top">
                <div class="chatbox-avatar">
                    <img src="../NewFolder/avatar.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-partner-name">
                    <span class="status online"></span>
                    <a target="_blank">Joe</a>
                </div>
                <button class="minimize-window" @onclick(minimize)></button>

            </div>
```

Here I am setting the button class and using @onclick to trigger the functionality to minimize.

My CSS is setting the button size

```
.minimize-window {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

Now I have declared a blazor component here as a function but I am not sure how C# works in respect to minimizing this window and I feel like I am missing some code that I would have to use.

```
@functions {
    void minimize()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: So, I don't think this is possible with C# and html. In my research, I can still use JS as a script in the HTML file, and C# is used more as a back-end for the web app for logic and communication.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an C# variable to preserve the state of your chat box.

```
@functions {
    bool isMinimized = false;
    void minimize()
    {
         isMinimized = true;
    }
    void maximize()
    {
         isMinimized = false;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this variable to render the needed html or just set an css class. Something like that

```
@if (isMinimized)
{
    <div class="chatbox-holder">
        <button class="maximize-window" @onclick(maximize)></button>
     </div>
}else{
<div class="chatbox-holder">
        <div class="chatbox">
            <div class="chatbox-top">
                <div class="chatbox-avatar">
                    <img src="../NewFolder/avatar.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-partner-name">
                    <span class="status online"></span>
                    <a target="_blank">Joe</a>
                </div>
                <button class="minimize-window" @onclick(minimize)></button>

            </div>
     </div>
 </div>
}
```